# Attempting to generate a alphabetic character string of varied length but am unable to successfully output

Tags: c#

I've seen posts similar to the question I am asking but I was unable to either understand or extract a solution that I am able to implement from them. My goal is to generate a string of alphabetic characters based on varied random length and pad the generated values with spaces, zero's and other characters.

As you can hopefully see from the below code, I am passing in a value, ("Left" or "Right") to the FirstNameGenerator(). It's an "object" type because the value is retrieved from an enum. I've instantiated a random object, created a string of alphabetic characters, set an integer variable ("size") to a value between 0 and 35, created a char array and passed in the ("size") random integer value and created a StreamWriter to write the data out to a file.

The issue is, the padding is not getting added to the generated value. The random data generated is perfect for what I need (junk test data) but I just need to get the padding added to the generated values and I'd be thrilled. I've added the PadRight/PadLeft method to the "return" statement as well, "return new string(buffer).PadRight(paddingAmount, paddingCharacter);" but that didn't work. Still got the random generated value without the padding. I also tried adding it in the main method after it was returned but it failed to add the padding to the output there too.

Any guidance would be deeply appreciated. I am just starting out with code. This is pretty much my first attempt and I've been at for 2 days now. I am sure there are a lot better ways to accomplish this task that more experienced coders could rattle off in a second so if anyone has any input, guidance or constructive criticism - I'm all ears.

Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RondomGenerators
{
class RandomGenerators
{
    public string FirstNameGenerator(int paddingAmount, char paddingCharacter, object paddingDirection)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        const string alphaChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int size = rand.Next(0, 35);
        char[] buffer = new char[size];
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\RondomGenerators\RondomGenerators\GenData\output.txt", false))

        if (paddingDirection.ToString().Contains("Right"))   
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                buffer[i] = alphaChars[rand.Next(alphaChars.Length)];
                new string(buffer).PadRight(paddingAmount, paddingCharacter);
                file.WriteLine(buffer);
            }
        else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                buffer[i] = alphaChars[rand.Next(alphaChars.Length)];
                new string(buffer).PadLeft(paddingAmount, paddingCharacter);
                file.WriteLine(buffer);
            }
        return new string(buffer);
     }
   }
}
```

IN MAIN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace RondomGenerators
{
class Program
{

    enum paddingDirection { Right, Left };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RandomGenerators fname = new RandomGenerators();
        Console.WriteLine(fname.FirstNameGenerator(15, 'X', paddingDirection.Right));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the padding but not storing the result back in the buffer.

Try:

```
buffer=new string(buffer).PadLeft(paddingAmount,paddingCharacter).ToCharArray();
```

And the same with PadRight.

Also, why are you using a buffer at all? Consider just sticking to strings altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I really appreciate it! I would have really liked to use just strings but I couldn't figure out how to get it working. I will give it another shot tomorrow though. Thanks again for the answer!